# Customize List View Item in Nokia Qt App

Tags: qt, listview, symbian, nokia, listviewitem

I am writing a simple file browser app with Nokia Qt4.7 on Symbian^3 platform. I can display the directory/file list in the listview widget using QFileSystemModel. But I want to customize the list view item. And I am using QItemDelegate to do the trick overriding sizHint and paint functions. I want to display a checkbox in the end of every item (ListMode) or in the right down corder of the icon(IconMode). How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to reimplement [QItemDelegate::paint](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qitemdelegate.html#paint) function and use QStylePainter and use [QStylePainter::drawControl](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstylepainter.html#drawControl) to render checkbox element. Depending on the mode you can vary your painting.

Comment: Is there any example code about reimplementing QItemDelegate::paint and QStylePainter::drawControl ?

Comment: yes, the method documentation itself has some small code. Also you can check out examples/itemviews/pixelator in Qt source code directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using QML . Styling rows is much easier in QML.
To be more specific your Model will still be c++ . Only the list can be in QML.